# Loading spinner is not showing at the bottom of infinite scroll

Tags: html, css, ionic-framework

I want to add the loading spinner at the bottom of infinite scroll, however after I added the codes, somehow it is not showing up at the bottom. I am quite new to all of these.

[image: Loading spinner somehow not showing up at the bottom of infinite scroll]

```
<ion-infinite-scroll #infinite (ionInfinite)="getProducts($event)">
  <ion-infinite-scroll-content loadingSpinner="crescent" content="loading.."></ion-infinite-scroll-content>
</ion-infinite-scroll>
```

Answer (score 1):

I found this here [Ionic Spinner not showing up](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36397338/ionic-spinner-not-showing-up).
Check it out if it works, not sure.

```
.my-spinner{
z-index: 99999999 !important;
position: absolute;
bottom:0px;
left:45%;
right:45%;
}


//template
<ion-infinite-scroll
    ng-if="!noMoreItemsAvailable"
    icon="ion-load-d"
    on-infinite="getpagenation()"
    distance="1%">
  </ion-infinite-scroll>

<div  ng-if="!noMoreItemsAvailable">
      <ion-spinner ng-show="ItemLoading" icon="ios" class="spinner spinner-ios my-spinner">
</div>



//js
$scope.getpagenation = function() {
        $scope.ItemLoading = true;
 //you can call services

 //have items
        $scope.ItemLoading = false;
 //no more items
        $scope.noMoreItemsAvailable = true;
        $scope.ItemLoading = false;
        $scope.$broadcast('scroll.infiniteScrollComplete');
}
```

Comment: Give it a try, if still give any error thn ping me.